# Azure Service Bus through Azure API Management

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-api-management

We are considering improving security management around our Azure Service Bus stack used a an Enterprise Service Bus.

Azure API management seems a pretty good candidate (and would allow plenty other usages in our ecosystem) but is there any cons behind ?

For example, service bus can connect with `Http/Https/Tcp` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode?view=azure-dotnet)

As far as I can tell, when possible, `Tcp` would provide better performance (?), but I suspect it won't be supported anymore if exposed with Azure API Management ?

Is there other limitations to expect ? as an example, 'older' (replaced) javascript library relied on SB REST API (https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-sb) had some limitations such missing `Defer` / `Abandon` (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/2019)

Answer (score 0):

From APIM perspective:

1. You will have to use HTTP since that is the only protocol APIM supports.
2. APIM will introduce additional hop in your network, that will affect latency.
3. APIM does not maintain any connection affinity between client and backend, i.e. requests received from multiple clients over multiple connections may be sent to backend over single connection, and other way around.